# Trying to extend to base file in Django

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

So I am trying to extend many files (let's name them **sidebar1.html**, **sidebar2.html** AND **content.html**) to 1 main file (**global.html**)

The problem is whenever I run it, it doesn't show the sidebar but it shows the contents of content.html.

this is the global page (for side bar):

```
    <div style="color: white;">

    {% block sidebar %}

    {% endblock %}

    </div>
```

and this is the global page (for content):

```
    <div class="segment">
        <div class="container" style="margin:25px 35px 10px 300px;">

        {% block main %}

        {% endblock %}

        </div>
    </div>
```

sample content:

```
    {% extends "global_base_ui.html" %}

    {% block main %}

        content

    {% endblock %}
```

this is the side bar content:

```
    {% extends 'global_base_ui.html' %}

    {% block sidebar %}
        <div class="item">
            <a class="title">
                <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                <b>Manager's Tools</b>
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: The problem here is you are using extend multiple times. Better to use block content and end block only to the your content.html, and use include tag for both of your side bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending can only used for one template to extend another. You can't do multiple `{% extends 'base.html' %}`, at least in django 2.x...

**You probably want to use an `{% include 'some_other_template.html' %}`**

So put the template you want to include in another template, and now you only have to edit 1 file. Very useful for contact info, etc, in multiple places.